# Problems when changing PHP/SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

On my website I have a page that can only be viewed if the persons details are in a table called Members, the values are posted from a form in the previous page. This is the original code I had and it worked fine:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE firstname='" . $firstname . "' and surname='" . 
$surname. "'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($rows == 1) 
{ 
   //user continues loading page
} 
else 
{ 
   header ('location: signup.html'); //user is redirected to sign up page 
}
```

After some changes to the site, I now require the same user to have to have paid='TRUE' in the Members table to continue loading the page. This is the code I came up with:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE firstname='" . $firstname . "' and surname='" . 
$surname. "'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

$query = "SELECT paid FROM Members WHERE firstname='" . $firstname . "' and surname='" . 
$surname. "'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
$paid = mysql_num_rows($result);


if ($rows == 1 && $paid=='TRUE') 
{ 
   //user continues loading page
} 
else 
{ 
   header ('location: signup.html'); //user is redirected to sign up page 
 }
```

With this new code, even if the user has paid it re-directs them to the signup page... Have I gone about this the wrong way?

Comment: is "PAID" a column in the members table?

Comment: $paid = [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)($result) will be set as an integer, so $paid == 'TRUE' is of no use. Second mysql_* is deprecated, try using PDO or mysqli

Comment: mysql_num_rows would return 1 in your case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You check $paid against 'TRUE' but fill it with mysql_num_rows.
Try:

```
if ($rows > 0  && $paid >0 )
```

instead.

Plus, since I can not see if you escape your strings properly, please take note that $firstname and $surname should be escaped/verified.

Anyway you can skip the second mysql_query and use:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE firstname='" . $firstname . "' and surname='" . 
    $surname. "'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if( $rows ){

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        if($row['paid'] =='TRUE') {
            //continue
        } else {
    //redirect
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE firstname = '" . $firstname . "' and surname = '" . $surname. "' and paid = 'true'";
$rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query));

if ($rows == 1) { 
   //user continues loading page
} 
else { 
   header ('location: signup.html'); //user is redirected to sign up page 
}
```

you must also be sure to check for sql injection in `$firstname` and `$surname`!

Answer (score 3):

You code is wrong. This should be OK:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE firstname='" . $firstname . "' and surname='" . $surname. "'"; 
$resource = mysql_query($query);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($rows) { 
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);
    if($result['paid'] == 'TRUE') {
        //user continues loading page
    } else {
        // user has not paid, redirect him to payment page
    }
} else { 
    header ('location: signup.html'); //user is redirected to sign up page 
}
```

Anyway, I recommend to start using `mysqli` or `PDO` as `mysql_*` functions are already deprecated.